MAUI Keyboardshortcut not work after entering fullscreen
I am implementing a YouTube's full screen like feature in MAUI.
I implemented the fullscreen functionality, but ran into a problem implementing the keyboard shortcut functionality.
When I hide the NavBar at the top of MAUI (Shell.NavBarIsVisible=“False”) KeyboardAccelerator does not work.
How can I implement the keyboard shortcut function while keeping the full screen?

Have you tried to intercept manually the OnKeyDown event?
